# Oracle INSERT Triggers With IF

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger but get an error.
Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong, I will be more than grateful. It's for part of my college final project.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger
AFTER
INSERT
ON TESTRESULTS
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    NEW_CASEID        Integer;
    RESULT            Char(3);

BEGIN
    RESULT = :new.Result;

    IF :new.PUIID IS IN (SELECT PUIID FROM CASE)THEN
       SELECT CASEID INTO NEW_CASEID 
       FROM CASE
       WHERE PUIID = :new.PUIID;

       INSERT INTO  CASEEVENT
       (CASEEVENTID, CASEID, EventDate, EventComments, MethodOfCommunication, CreatedBy, CreationDate, LastUpdateBy, LastUpdateDate)
           VALUES
           (CASEEVENTID_PK.NextVal, New_CaseID, :new.Date, 'New Test Result Available: include here the test result',
               Null, 'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger',SYSDATE,Null,Null);

     ELSEIF RESULT = 'PST' THEN
         INSERT INTO CASE
         (CASEID, PUIID, ActivationDate, ClosingDate, ClosingReason, ExposureTypeID, CaseWorkerID, CreatedBy,CreationDate, LastUpdateBy, LastUpdateDate)
         VALUES
         (CASEID_PK.NextVal, :new.PUIID, SYSDATE,NUll,NUll,NUll,'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger',SYSDATE,NUll,NUll);

          INSERT INTO  CASEEVENT
       (CASEEVENTID, CASEID, EventDate, EventComments, MethodOfCommunication, CreatedBy, CreationDate, LastUpdateBy, LastUpdateDate)
           VALUES
           (CASEEVENTID_PK.NextVal, CASEID_PK.CurrVal, :new.Date, 'New Test Result Available: include here the test result',
               Null, 'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger',SYSDATE,Null,Null);
     END IF;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

The fact that you got an error is less than useful. How are we supposed to guess which one?

Anyway, I tried to review code you wrote; here's what is obviously wrong:

- you declared `result char(3)` - beware of `char` datatype as it right-pads value with spaces up to total column length. Safer option is to use `VARCHAR2`. But, if those results really are strings whose length is always 3 characters, then OK - use it.
- not `result = :new.result`, but `result := :new.result` (missing colon)
- `IF :new.PUIID IS IN (SELECT PUIID FROM CASE) THEN` - two errors here:

  - you can't use subquery in this context. First find out whether `:new.puiid` exists in the `case` table (which means that you'll have to declare additional local variable), then use it in `IF`
  - even if you could use the subquery, it is not `if :new.puiid IS in` but `if :new.puiid in` (without "is")
- it is not `elseif` but `elsif`
- `insert into case` is wrong. You named 11 columns to be inserted, but provided 10 values. Fix that.
- `insert into caseevent`: you are inserting `:new.date`. `date` is invalid column name as it is reserved for the datatype name. That seems to be *generally* wrong, unless you used double quotes when naming the column, and that's again *generally* wrong as you should avoid double quotes in Oracle while creating objects

---

As I don't have your tables, I can't test it. However, here's code which *might* work (if you fix that "10 values into 11 columns" issue.

```
create or replace trigger newtest_caseevent_trigger 
  after insert on testresults
  for each row 
declare
  new_caseid  integer;
  result      char(3);           -- beware of CHAR!
  l_puuid     case.puiid%type;   -- newly declared variable
begin 
  result := :new.result;         --  add ":"

  -- subquery can't be used in IF, so you'll have to find whether :new.puiid
  -- exists in that table separately
  select max(puiid) into l_puiid from case where puiid = :new.puiid;

  if l_puiid is not null then
     select caseid 
       into new_caseid 
       from case
       where puiid = :new.puiid;

     insert into caseevent
       (caseeventid, caseid, eventdate, 
        eventcomments, 
        methodofcommunication, createdby, creationdate, 
        lastupdateby, lastupdatedate)
     values
       (caseeventid_pk.nextval, new_caseid, :new.date, 
        'New Test Result Available: include here the test result',
        null, 'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger',sysdate,
        null,null);

   elsif result = 'PST' then    -- "elsif", not "elseif"
      -- you are inserting 10 values into 11 columns; that won't work
      insert into case
        (caseid, puiid, activationdate, closingdate, 
         closingreason, exposuretypeid, caseworkerid, createdby,
         creationdate, lastupdateby, lastupdatedate)
      values
        (caseid_pk.nextval, :new.puiid, sysdate, null,
         null, null, 'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger', sysdate,
         null, null);

      insert into caseevent
        (caseeventid, caseid, eventdate, 
         eventcomments, 
         methodofcommunication, createdby, creationdate, lastupdateby, lastupdatedate)
      values
        (caseeventid_pk.nextval, caseid_pk.currval, :new.date,
         'New Test Result Available: include here the test result',
         null, 'NewTest_CaseEvent_Trigger', sysdate, null, null); 
  end if;
end;
/
```